Accessing internet from Strongswan / IKE2 VPN with nftables
I have a Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS server, running Strongswan.
I have since learned that it's using nftables and not iptables for its firewall.
In setting up the VPN, I am able to connect with the client, but I'm not able to access hosts on the internet by ip address, or resolve names.
I think I'm missing some of the forwarding rules, but I'm not sure how to translate/apply them in a nft format.
What rule(s) do I need to apply to have IPV4 and IPV6 work for the clients?
The below config started out from a wireguard guide and I modified it to include other services I have on the machine. I found some references from openwrt and strongswan and tried to translate that, but I think I have not met the mark yet. I appreciate any advice.
Thank you.
I added these in an attempt to pass the ipsec traffic
chain prerouting
 meta ipsec exists ip saddr $IKE_NETS counter accept

chain inbound_world

    meta l4proto ah accept
    meta l4proto esp accept

/etc/nftables.conf
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

define DEV_WG = wg0
define DEV_OVPN = tun0
define DEV_VPN = { $DEV_WG, $DEV_OVPN }
define DEV_WORLD = eth0
define IP_OVPN = 10.8.0.0/24
define IP_WORLD_V4 = public_v4_ip
define IP_WORLD_V6 = public_v6_ip
define PORT_IKE = { 500, 4500 }
define PORT_WG = 51820
define PORT_OVPN = 1194
define PORT_VPN = { $PORT_IKE, $PORT_WG, $PORT_OVPN  }
define DEV_LOCAL_NETS = { $DEV_VPN }
define DEV_OUT_NETS = { $DEV_WORLD }
#define IKE_NETS = { 172.16.252.0/24, fd5a:4c1f:8d73:f583::/64 } <- did not like the Ipv6 address
define IKE_NETS = { 172.16.252.0/24 }


# `inet` applies to both IPv4 and IPv6.
table inet global {
    map port_forwards_tcp_ipv4 {
        type ipv4_addr . inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service
        # lets forward port for our torrent. Our 12345 to 12345 on 172.16.0.2
        elements = { $IP_WORLD_V4 . 12345 : 172.16.0.2 . 12345 }
    }

    map port_forwards_tcp_ipv6 {
        type ipv6_addr . inet_service : ipv6_addr . inet_service
        # lets forward port for our torrent. Our 12345 to 12345 on fdf5:6028:947d:1234::2
        elements = { $IP_WORLD_V6 . 12345 : [fdf5:6028:947d:1234::2] . 12345}
    }

    map port_forwards_udp_ipv4 {
        type ipv4_addr . inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service
        # lets forward port for our torrent. Our 12345 to 12345 on 172.16.0.2
        elements = { $IP_WORLD_V4 . 12345 : 172.16.0.2 . 12345 }
    }

    map port_forwards_udp_ipv6 {
        type ipv6_addr . inet_service : ipv6_addr . inet_service
        # lets forward port for our torrent. Our 12345 to 12345 on fdf5:6028:947d:1234::2
        elements = { $IP_WORLD_V6 . 12345 : [fdf5:6028:947d:1234::2] . 12345}
    }

    chain inbound_world {
        # accepting ping (icmp-echo-request) for diagnostic purposes.
        # However, it also lets probes discover this host is alive.
        # This sample accepts them within a certain rate limit:
        #
        # icmp type echo-request limit rate 5/second accept

        # Allow IPv6 configuration packets
        icmpv6 type {nd-neighbor-solicit,nd-neighbor-advert,nd-router-solicit, 
             nd-router-advert,mld-listener-query,destination-unreachable,
             packet-too-big,time-exceeded,parameter-problem} accept

        # allow SSH
        tcp dport { 22 } accept

        # http, https
        tcp dport 80 accept
        tcp dport 443 accept

        # smtp, submission, smtps
        tcp dport 25 accept
        tcp dport 587 accept
        tcp dport 465 accept

        # pop3, pop3s
        tcp dport 110 accept
        tcp dport 995 accept

        # imap, imaps
        tcp dport 143 accept
        tcp dport 993 accept

       # allow VPN connection
    udp dport { $PORT_VPN } accept

    meta l4proto ah accept
    meta l4proto esp accept
    }

    chain inbound_vpn {
        # accepting ping (icmp-echo-request) for diagnostic purposes.
        icmp type echo-request limit rate 5/second accept

        # Allow IPv6 configuration packets
        icmpv6 type {nd-neighbor-solicit,nd-neighbor-advert,nd-router-solicit,
             nd-router-advert,mld-listener-query,destination-unreachable,
             packet-too-big,time-exceeded,parameter-problem} accept

        # allow DNS and SSH from the private network
        tcp dport { 22, 53 } accept
        udp dport { 53 } accept
    }

    chain inbound {
        # drop all traffic by default
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;

        # Allow traffic from established and related packets, drop invalid
        ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }
        # Allow dnat (port forwarding)
        ct status dnat accept

        # allow loopback traffic, anything else jump to chain for further evaluation
        iifname vmap { lo : accept, $DEV_WORLD : jump inbound_world, $DEV_VPN : jump inbound_vpn}

        # the rest is dropped by the above policy
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;

        # Allow traffic from established and related packets, drop invalid
        ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }
        # Allow port forwarding
        ct status dnat accept

        # connections from the internal nets to the out nets are allowed
        iifname $DEV_LOCAL_NETS oifname $DEV_OUT_NETS accept
        # the rest is dropped by the above policy
        meta ipsec exists ip saddr $IKE_NETS counter accept


    }

    chain prerouting {
       type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
       dnat ip addr . port to ip daddr . tcp dport map @port_forwards_tcp_ipv4
       dnat ip6 addr . port to ip6 daddr . tcp dport map @port_forwards_tcp_ipv6
       dnat ip addr . port to ip daddr . udp dport map @port_forwards_udp_ipv4
       dnat ip6 addr . port to ip6 daddr . udp dport map @port_forwards_udp_ipv6
       meta ipsec exists ip saddr $IKE_NETS counter accept
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        # Hide IPs from local nets to the internet.
        # We are using SNAT because we have static IP and it wil work faster than MASQUERADE
        iifname $DEV_LOCAL_NETS oifname $DEV_WORLD snat ip to $IP_WORLD_V4
        iifname $DEV_LOCAL_NETS oifname $DEV_WORLD snat ip6 to $IP_WORLD_V6
    }
}

Strongswan pools:
pools {
    primary-pool-ipv4 {
        addrs = 172.16.252.0/24
        dns = 172.16.252.1, 8.8.8.8, 9.9.9.9
        split_exclude = 172.16.0.0/12
    }
    primary-pool-ipv6 {
        addrs = fd5a:4c1f:8d73:f583::/64
    dns = 2620:fe::fe, 2620:fe::9

    }


Working implementation on my server for IPSEC and other VPNS.
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
#to reload: nft -f /etc/nftables.conf
flush ruleset

define DEV_WG = wg0
define DEV_OVPN = tun0
define DEV_VPN = { $DEV_WG, $DEV_OVPN }
define DEV_WORLD = eth0
define IP_OVPN = 10.8.0.0/24
define IP_WORLD_V4 = YOURIP4ADDRESS
define IP_WORLD_V6 = YOURIP6ADDRESS
define PORT_IKE = { 500, 4500 }
define PORT_WG = 51820
define PORT_OVPN = 1194
define PORT_VPN = { $PORT_IKE, $PORT_WG, $PORT_OVPN  }
define DEV_LOCAL_NETS = { $DEV_VPN }
define DEV_OUT_NETS = { $DEV_WORLD }
define IKE_NET6 = { fd5a:4c1f:8d73:f583::/64 }
define IKE_NETS = { 172.16.252.0/24 }



# `inet` applies to both IPv4 and IPv6.
table inet global {
    map port_forwards_tcp_ipv4 {
        type ipv4_addr . inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service
        # lets forward port for our torrent. Our 12345 to 12345 on 172.16.0.2
        elements = { $IP_WORLD_V4 . 12345 : 172.16.0.2 . 12345 }
    }

    map port_forwards_tcp_ipv6 {
        type ipv6_addr . inet_service : ipv6_addr . inet_service
        # lets forward port for our torrent. Our 12345 to 12345 on fdf5:6028:947d:1234::2
        elements = { $IP_WORLD_V6 . 12345 : [fdf5:6028:947d:1234::2] . 12345}
    }

    map port_forwards_udp_ipv4 {
        type ipv4_addr . inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service
        # lets forward port for our torrent. Our 12345 to 12345 on 172.16.0.2
        elements = { $IP_WORLD_V4 . 12345 : 172.16.0.2 . 12345 }
    }

    map port_forwards_udp_ipv6 {
        type ipv6_addr . inet_service : ipv6_addr . inet_service
        # lets forward port for our torrent. Our 12345 to 12345 on fdf5:6028:947d:1234::2
        elements = { $IP_WORLD_V6 . 12345 : [fdf5:6028:947d:1234::2] . 12345}
    }

    chain inbound_world {
        # accepting ping (icmp-echo-request) for diagnostic purposes.
        # However, it also lets probes discover this host is alive.
        # This sample accepts them within a certain rate limit:
        #
        # icmp type echo-request limit rate 5/second accept

        # Allow IPv6 configuration packets
        icmpv6 type {nd-neighbor-solicit,nd-neighbor-advert,nd-router-solicit,
             nd-router-advert,mld-listener-query,destination-unreachable,
             packet-too-big,time-exceeded,parameter-problem} accept

        # allow SSH
        tcp dport { 22 } accept

        # http, https
        tcp dport 80 accept
        tcp dport 443 accept

        # smtp, submission, smtps
        tcp dport 25 accept
        tcp dport 587 accept
        tcp dport 465 accept

        # pop3, pop3s
        tcp dport 110 accept
        tcp dport 995 accept

        # imap, imaps
        tcp dport 143 accept
        tcp dport 993 accept

       # allow VPN connection
    udp dport { $PORT_VPN } accept

    meta l4proto ah  counter accept comment "AH accept"
    meta l4proto esp  counter accept  comment "ESP Accept"
    }

    chain inbound_vpn {
        # accepting ping (icmp-echo-request) for diagnostic purposes.
        icmp type echo-request limit rate 5/second accept

        # Allow IPv6 configuration packets
        icmpv6 type {nd-neighbor-solicit,nd-neighbor-advert,nd-router-solicit,
             nd-router-advert,mld-listener-query,destination-unreachable,
             packet-too-big,time-exceeded,parameter-problem} accept

        # allow DNS and SSH from the private network
        tcp dport { 22, 53 } accept
        udp dport { 53 } accept
    }

    chain inbound {
        # drop all traffic by default
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;

        # Allow traffic from established and related packets, drop invalid
        ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }
        # Allow dnat (port forwarding)
        ct status dnat accept

        # allow loopback traffic, anything else jump to chain for further evaluation
        iifname vmap { lo : accept, $DEV_WORLD : jump inbound_world, $DEV_VPN : jump inbound_vpn}

        # Allow VPN clients to communicate with each other.
        # iifname $DEV_VPN oifname $DEV_VPN ct state new accept

        # the rest is dropped by the above policy
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;

        # Allow traffic from established and related packets, drop invalid
        ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }
        # Allow port forwarding
        ct status dnat accept

        # connections from the internal nets to the out nets are allowed
        iifname $DEV_LOCAL_NETS oifname $DEV_OUT_NETS accept
        # the rest is dropped by the above policy

    #ipsec vpn config
        meta ipsec exists ip saddr $IKE_NETS counter accept comment "forward ipsec"
        meta ipsec exists ip6 saddr $IKE_NET6 counter accept comment "forward ipsec v6"


    }

    chain prerouting {
       type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
       dnat ip addr . port to ip daddr . tcp dport map @port_forwards_tcp_ipv4
       dnat ip6 addr . port to ip6 daddr . tcp dport map @port_forwards_tcp_ipv6
       dnat ip addr . port to ip daddr . udp dport map @port_forwards_udp_ipv4
       dnat ip6 addr . port to ip6 daddr . udp dport map @port_forwards_udp_ipv6

    #ipsec vpn config?
       meta ipsec exists ip saddr $IKE_NETS counter accept comment "prerouting ipsec v4"
       meta ipsec exists ip6 saddr $IKE_NET6 counter accept comment "prerouting ipsec v6"

    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        # Hide IPs from local nets to the internet.
        # We are using SNAT because we have static IP and it wil work faster than MASQUERADE
        ip saddr $IKE_NETS oifname $DEV_WORLD counter snat ip to $IP_WORLD_V4 comment "postrouting ipsec v4"
        ip6 saddr $IKE_NET6 oifname $DEV_WORLD counter snat ip6 to $IP_WORLD_V6 comment "postrouting ipsec v6"

        iifname $DEV_LOCAL_NETS oifname $DEV_WORLD snat ip to $IP_WORLD_V4
        iifname $DEV_LOCAL_NETS oifname $DEV_WORLD snat ip6 to $IP_WORLD_V6
    }

#End of Table
}

